# How to add action specific asset pipeline items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I am writing a Rails 3.2.1 application and I have some javascript code I'd like to put in for a single action view. It simply calls a jquery plugin and starts a countdown, but I'd like to write it in coffee script and I feel like the asset pipeline is the correct tool to do this.

Also I need access to the variables passed by the controller such as `@question`. **How would I do this?** I have looked into the `coffeebeans` gem but that only works for `:remote=>true` forms and links.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566129/how-to-namespace-our-js-for-use-with-the-rails-asset-pipeline/8568208#8568208

Comment: On the access to variable parts, there's a railscast for it. [Passing Data to Javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript). =)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved in different ways.

## Add the assets dynamically

1. Add to our application helper the following method:

   ```
   module ApplicationHelper
       def include_related_asset(asset)
       #          v-----{Change this}
           if !YourApp::Application.assets.find_asset(asset).nil?
               case asset.split('.')[-1]
                   when 'js'
                       javascript_include_tag asset
                   when 'css'
                       stylesheet_link_tag asset
               end
           end
       end
   end
   ```
2. Call the helper method in your `layout`-file:

   ```
   <%= include_related_asset(params[:controller].to_param + '_' + params[:action].to_param . 'js') %>
   ```
3. Create specific assets for your controller actions. E. g. `controller_action.js`

## Use `yield`

1. Add `<%= yield :head%>` to your layout head
2. Include your assets from your action views:

   ```
   <% content_for :head do %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'controller_action' %>
   <% end %>
   ```

Please see the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) for further information.

---

To passing controller data to your javascript, you could do:

```
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
        window.error_message = '<%= j error_message %>';
    <% end %>
```

Please see the [RailCast Episode #324](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) for further information.